# PHP 5.4.16 COM can create/save new Word files, hangs when opening existing files

Tags: php, windows-7, com, ms-word

Windows 7 Professional x64 - WAMP Server 2.4

Apache Version (x32): 2.4.4

PHP Version (x32): 5.4.16

Office 2003 - Same version as old server

I have a legacy program that reads local  .doc files on a shared drive, inserts content into bookmarks, and then saves these files before they are converted to .pdfs and emailed to our clients. Before anybody else tells me, [I am VERY AWARE that this is not a recommended or supported way to do things.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) Just need to get this legacy code working on new hardware so I can finish work on a newer piece of software that will eventually replace this and avoid COM scripting all together.

Recently the server that runs this software has become unbearably slow. We're setting up a new server to move it over to, but I've encountered a show-stopping critical error with the software on the new environment:

The following code WORKS AND HAS NO PROBLEMS:

```
// starting word
$word = new COM("Word.Application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word");
echo "Loaded Word, version {$word->Version}\n";

$word->Visible = 0;

//open an empty document
$word->Documents->Add();
$word->Selection->TypeText("This is a test...");
$word->ActiveDocument->saveAs('C:\test.doc');

echo "File saved\n";

//closing word
$word->Quit();

//free the object
$word = null;

echo "Word closed\n";
```

The following code just hangs forever and never gets past the $word->Documents->Open(); line.

```
// starting word
$word = new COM("Word.Application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word");
echo "Loaded Word, version {$word->Version}\n";

//bring it to front
$word->Visible = 0;

$word->Documents->Open('C:\test.doc') or die ('Could not open file');

//closing word
$word->Quit();

//free the object
$word = null;

echo "Word closed\n";
```

PLEASE HELP! Seeing that the PHP/COM can create a new file and save it makes me feel like this is possible, but there's some permissions issue hiding behind the scenes preventing Word from opening existing files.

Answer (score 1):

Apache services need 1 window account have permission network to start it.
Simple you need start apache via command to test.